# Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type File is not JSON serializable but no other solution working for me

Tags: discord, discord.py

**The Function of discord command named server**

````py
@bot.command(name = 'server')
async def _minecraftserverinfo(ctx, ip:str, port:str, servername:str):
    if servername == "survival":
        svname = "Survival"
    elif servername == "lobby":
        svname = "Lobby"
    #serverembed = createEmbed(ip, port)
    #value = f"The server has {status.players.online} players and replied in {status.latency} ms\nThe server replied in {latency} ms\nThe server has the following players online: {','.join(query.players.names)}"
    server = MinecraftServer.lookup(ip+':'+port)

#=======================================

#=======================================
    # 'status' is supported by all Minecraft servers that are version 1.7 or higher.
    status = server.status()
    latency = server.ping()
    query = server.query()
    serverembed = discord.Embed(title = ip, url = "https://www.zer02infinity.com/",description = f"Zero To Infinity Minecraft {svname} Server")#\nThe server has the following players online: {','.join(query.players.names)}")
    serverembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833829693588373534/920017091325747220/2021-12-13_11.png")
    serverembed.add_field(name="Players Count", value=f"{status.players.online}/{query.players.max}", inline=True)
    serverembed.add_field(name="Direct Connect:", value=f"```mc.zer02infinity.com```", inline=True)

    #serverembed.add_field(name="Names:", value=f"{latency} ms", inline=True)
    #nl = '\n'
    #serverembed.add_field(name="Names:", value=f"{nl}{nl.join(query.players.names)}", inline=False)
    #serverembed.add_field(name="Names:", value={'\n'.join(query.players.ping)}, inline=True)

    #sending embed
    embed = await ctx.send(embed=serverembed)
    await embed.add_reaction(emoji)
    message_id = embed.id
    while True:
        server = MinecraftServer.lookup(ip+':'+port)
            # 'status' is supported by all Minecraft servers that are version 1.7 or higher.
        status = server.status()
        latency = server.ping()
        query = server.query()
        serverembed = discord.Embed(title = ip, url = "https://www.zer02infinity.com/",description = f"Zero To Infinity Minecraft {svname} Server")#\nThe server has the following players online: {','.join(query.players.names)}")
        serverembed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833829693588373534/920017091325747220/2021-12-13_11.png")
        serverembed.add_field(name="Players Count", value=f"{status.players.online}/{query.players.max}", inline=True)
        serverembed.add_field(name="Direct Connect:", value=f"```mc.zer02infinity.com```", inline=True)
        #serverembed.add_field(name="Names:", value=f"{latency} ms", inline=True)
        #nl = '\n'
````

**problem started after i added a image from local file**

```py
        file = discord.File("./foo.png", filename="foo.png")
        serverembed.add_field(name="Names:", value={','.join(query.players.names)}, inline=False)
        serverembed.set_image(url="attachment://foo.png")
        #print('Winners are:', *names, sep='\n')
        serverembed = await embed.edit(file=file, embed = serverembed)
        await asyncio.sleep(60)
        pass
```

**So this is the recent code i added where foo.png is maintained by graph.py given below**

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Equations(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    def plotlineareq(self, a, b, clr):
        x = [0, 10]
        y = [(a * i + b) for i in x]
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))  # #Size of Graph
        plt.xlim(x)  # #X Range [-6,6]
        plt.ylim(x)  # #Y Range [-6,6]
        axis = plt.gca()  # #Get Current Axis
        plt.plot(axis.get_xlim(), [0, 0], 'k--')  # #X Axis Plots Line Across
        plt.plot([0, 0], axis.get_ylim(), 'k--')  # #Y Axis Plots Line Across
        plt.locator_params(axis="x", nbins=20)
        plt.locator_params(axis="y", nbins=20)
        plt.plot(x, y, label='linear', linestyle='solid', color=clr)
        plt.ylabel('Players')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        mm = str(a)
        bb = str(b)
        plt.title('Live Status')
        #plt.grid()
        plt.savefig("foo.png")

    @commands.command()
    async def linear(self, ctx, equation):
        try:
            equation = equation.replace(" ", "")
            mx = equation.split("x")[0]
            mx = equation.replace("x", "").replace("y=", "")
            bx = equation.split("+")[1]
            self.plotlineareq(mx, bx, 'b')
            file = discord.File("foo.png", filename='foo.png')
            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xff0000)
            embed = embed.set_image(url="attachment://foo.png")
            await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)

        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"An error occured: {e}")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Equations(bot))
```

After executing it gives the following error in error log-

> Command raised an exception: TypeError: Object of type File is not JSON serializable

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] and not this much code you have given. And please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.